# Running the 'Blank activity' on Android Studio error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.0

When I try to run the default 'Hello world' activity or blank activity I get the following error:

minSdk(API 23, N preview) != deviceSdk(API 23)

I'm using Android Studio 2.0 and I have tried multiple Virtual Devices. (Nexus 4, 5, 6P) But they all gave the same error. I updated and installed a lot of files on the SDK manager. I have no clue what the problem is. Again I haven't changed the file, it is just the standard Blank activity. I just installed Android Studio and I'm new in this area. I hope it's a common mistake or error. Can someone help me out please? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have set up the project to use the N Developer Preview, which means that it will only run on N Developer Preview devices and emulators.

Assuming that this is a typical Android Studio project, open `app/build.gradle`. In there, you will see `minSdkVersion`, `targetSdkVersion`, and `compileSdkVersion`. Probably all are set to `'N'`. If that is not what you want, change them to something else (e.g., 23).